# Is it ok to make characters fit unique and parodic archetypes?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, character-development

Is it ok to make characters fit unique and parodic archetypes, especially when trying to write a dark, gritty and realistic story? I was watching a video on the famous film director Akira Kurosawa, and I noticed he tell his actor to repeat one gesture and repeat it throughout the film, which makes the characters fit an unrealistic and almost parodic archetype. Is this ok? I think the Japanese base their screenwriting on Kabuki theatre and it is why the dialogues sometimes sound over the top and exaggerated, but I am wondering if doing this for a Western audience is ill-advised.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doaQC-S8de8

Answer (score 1):

Every person thinks and acts differently from each other, so it's not unusual for people to have unique personalities. Many people have mannerisms that they use a lot.
In western writing, characters aren't written as dramatically as in an anime or a manga. However, since it's not often seen here, if used properly, I think it could make some very interesting characters.

Hope this helped!